# How to encrypt a text

Tags: c++, encryption, encryption-asymmetric, public-key-encryption, aes

I need to implement a simple text encryption in C++ without using any existing framworks. This is purely for educational purpose to learn the in-and-outs and to learn the way to implement such a system. I am not planning to implement this in production code. I can use Windows APIs but it won't be cross platform. I am trying to learn something can work across multiple platforms. the best way to implement this is implement using C/C++. Please share good resources or links in this regard.

Comment: Encryption *without* using any existing frameworks is just asking for trouble. This is **not** something where you should feel free to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: How simple is simple? Caesar cipher, ROT13, or do you want strong cryptophy?

Comment: Is "without... frameworks" meant to mean no libraries, that you only want a simple system you can put together yourself?  Then why the aes and public key etc. tags? - they're not simple enough for someone who has to ask for leads....  If you are writing from scratch, then some other details would be useful: e.g. are both sides trusted?, can they securely exchange data in advance of the potentially eves-dropped-on exchanges? is it practical to put an upper limit on the volume of data they might exchange?  Potentially, your solution could be as simple as a one time pad and XOR....

Comment: It's for learning purpose. I am not going to use it in the public place or re-implement the entire things. I was trying to implement something something cross platforms using C/C++. So that I can learn things myself.

Comment: I updated the question details.

Comment: You could try, "Applied Cryptography" (Schneier), it's a decent introduction and covers simple encryption, but it's 15 years old and hence doesn't cover AES at all. "Cryptography Engineering" (Ferguson, Schneier, Kohno) is more recent, but I haven't read it and don't know what's in it.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you actually want, you could look at the [CipherSaber](http://ciphersaber.gurus.org/) project: instructions to implement your own RC4 encryption code for a simple IV+text format.

However this is an academic exercise only: you should never use your own crypto code in production unless you really know what you're doing. You could also read Schneier's Applied Cryptography for a good introduction to all of this stuff.

Comment: Please allow me to *not* trust any webpage using 9/11 to advertise themselves.

Comment: Wow, that's just craziness. Less propaganda, more code.

Comment: @Alexandre Uh, yeah, it didn't have that when I first looked at it.

Comment: @Cody Yeah, the only useful part is the algorithm description and the test-vectors I guess. I remember it from years ago and I don't think it was that crazy back then.